# How merge files in Hive partitioned and bucketed files into one big file?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hive-metastore

I am working on Azure HDInsight cluster for big data processing. A few days back I created a  partitioned and bucketed table in hive by merging many files.

Since Azure does not give any option to stop the cluster,therefore I had to delete the cluster to save the cost. The data is independently stored in Azure storage account. When I create new cluster using the same storage account, I can see the database and the table using HDFS commands but hive cannot read that database or table, maybe hive does not have metadata about that.

The only option I am left with is to merge all those partitioned and bucketed files into a single file and then create the table again. So is there any way by which I can migrate that table to another database or merge it so that it would be easier to migrate??

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `EXTERNAL TABLE` (with same properties as before) pointing to that `HDFS location`. Since you mentioned it has partitions you can run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE table-name` so that you can see partitions as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually there are delta folders within the partitions, since the table is created by inserting data from multiple files and as a result I am getting this error:              
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: wasb://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/hive/warehouse/cdr.db/cdr_main/district=XYZ is a directory not a file.

Comment: It looks like it's a different problem than in your original question! does the solution I gave allowed you to create table and fetch data and shows partitions? If that solves your initial question can you elaborate the issue , am having hard time to understand this issue. It would be better either asking a new question ( if this question is solved) with all the details or please edit this question to reflect your current problem .. Thanks

Comment: just to avoid this problem in future you should have used external hive metastore.

Comment: @Naga, it did create partitions but I cannot query the data or even count the records and since the table is created by merging many files hence delta folders do exist .

Comment: Without knowing how you're creating the table, structure of underlying data, and how delta files created I may not be able to help you

Comment: the table structure is: Create Table cdr_main
(actv_strt_dttm string,actv_end_dttm string,cell_site_id string)
PARTITIONED BY(district string)
CLUSTERED BY (cell_site_id) INTO 10 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true");